# Merge local version of Xcode project into the "master" project

Tags: xcode, git

So I have my repository (Git, Bitbucket) that I am working on and managing with Xcode. Few weeks ago I gave some 3rd party developer a .zip of my project, and asked him the add some stuff to the project (Google Analytics, etc.), now he gave me the .zip back with all the changes he made, but his version of the project is older than the current master version I am working on. How can I add all the changes from his copy while keeping my current version? Xcode has an amazing GUI for doing that every time I call `push`, and the same great interface is available with the FileMerge tool, but it will be terribly disgusting work to open every single file on the project in FileMerge to compare them... I tried comparing the folders of the projects but it's not as convenient as Xcode doing it automatically and only showing me conflicts...

Isn't there's a way of doing something like "Import changes from local version into main project?"

I have also tried to use the technic shown here but I can't see my new remote when trying to pull:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18400083/2242359

Comment: 1) If you know the commit you gave the developer, you can create a branch there and check that out.  2) Place the developers code over this directory and check this in.  Git should show you all the changes.  3) Last step is to merge this into your main branch (rebase should help)

Comment: Thank you for the tip... I ended up using FileMerge with the folders of both versions and manually juggled "choose left" and "choose right" for every file... Will definitely try your way next time... (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using `FileMerge` on the folder with the main `master` version (synced with the server) and the folder with the version with the other developer additions.

FileMerge was able to show me only the files with differences. I did have to go over them one by one and do the "choose left"/"choose right"/"choose both" dance, but I chose the "save" folder for the merged project as the folder of the master version (Yes, the one I was working on). That way when I finished going over the files I just closed `FileMerge`, opened `Xcode`, made sure everything works, and pushed the merged project to the server.

@osowskit's solution could've been more "good citizen" (or just less sketchy and more reversible) but the fact I merge into the folder I was comparing made it a little bit easier...